# Failed to resolve dependencies: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0

Tags: android, retrofit

```
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

I am getting this error

> Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
>
> Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0

I am using Android studio 3.1.3

I am adding these dependencies in the project i pulled from git

Comment: Please post your root and module `build.gradle`. Please clarify whether offline mode is enabled in Android Studio.

Comment: offline mode is disabled

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following block in your build.gradle file

```
 repositories 
    {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your android version is 2.3 and above and use like this
also check the update for java file

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
```

Comment: android studio version is 3.1.3